# AngularJS: nested directives & Two-Way Binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created a directive pgPaginator:

```
function PaginatorDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        templateUrl: 'paginator.html',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
        },
    };
}

// ...

.directive('pgPaginator', PaginatorDirective)
```

paginator.html:

```
<input pg-paginator-page />
<select pg-paginator-perpage ng-model="ngModel.perpage" ng-options="option for option in ngModel.perpageOptions"></select>
<br />
{{ngModel}}
<br />
{{ngModel.page}}
```

and i tryed to create another directive pg-paginator-page that use pgPaginator scope:

```
    .directive('pgPaginatorPage', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            template: '<input ng-model="ngModel.page" type="number" />',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log(scope)
            },
        }
    })
```

But when I create this directive, two-way binding is broken: http://embed.plnkr.co/h85hAk/preview

What am I doing wrong?